# Sequences of 'Rayleigh-like quotients' and their minima for a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $A$ be an $N\times N$ symmetric positive semi-definite matrix with eigenvalues $0 \leq \lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \dots \leq \lambda_N$ and corresponding eigenvectors $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_N$. Note that $A$ has real, non-negative eigenvalues and orthogonal eigenvectors.

Let there be a sequence of real, non-negative valued functions $f_n: (\mathbb{R}^N - \{0\}) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$, $n=1,2,\dots$ defined as
$$ 
f_n(x) := \left( \frac{x^t A^n x}{x^t x} \right)^{1/n},\quad x \in \mathbb{R}^N, x \neq 0 $$
Note that $f_n(x)$ has the appearance of a 'higher-order Rayleigh quotient'. $f_n(x)$ can be shown to satisfy the following properties:

- $f_n(x)$ is monotonically increasing for all $x$, i.e. for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $0 < n_1 < n_2$, we have $f_{n_1}(x) \leq f_{n_2}(x)$.
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f_n(x)$ does not exist (simply because approaching the origin in the direction of two eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues gives different limits).
- $f(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)$ exists for all non-zero $x$, i.e. $\{f_n\}$ converges *point-wise* to $f$. I don't know what can be said about uniform convergence, as both $f_n(x)$ and $f(x)$ are discontinuous.
- Let some non-zero $v \in \mathbb{R}^N$ be defined as $v = \sum_{i = 1}^{P} c_i u_i$, where $P\leq N$, $c_i$ are some scalars and $c_P \neq 0$. Then, $f(v) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(v) = \lambda_P$. This implies that the limit function $f(x)$ is discontinuous and assumes only a finite number of values.

Let a set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be defined as the set of vectors for which certain indices $\mathcal{S} \subset \{1,2,\dots,N\}$ are restricted to $0$, i.e. $\forall x \in X, x(\mathcal{S}) = 0$. It can easily be seen that $X$ is closed under vector addition, and thus is a *subspace* of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Let us define a sequence of real numbers $\{g_n\}$ associated with $\{f_n\}$ for the subspace $X \subset \mathbb{R}^N$. 
$$
g_n := \min_{x \in X} f_n(x)
$$ 
Note that minimization would be trivial if the set $X$ was equal to $\mathbb{R}^N$ itself, i.e. it would be similar to minimizing the Rayleigh quotient we normally know. Now, for $\{g_n\}$, it can be shown that

- The sequence $\{g_n\}$ is monotonically increasing, i.e. $0 < n_1 < n_2,\; g_{n_1} \leq g_{n_2}$.
- The sequence is also upper-bounded, which means it converges and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g_n$ exists.

**I would like to prove the following:** 
$$
\min_{x \in X} f(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g_n
$$

Intuitively, I have the following point in favor of this: Since $f_n(x)$ is lower bounded by $g_n$ for all $n$, I feel that it must also be true for the limit function as well. That is, $g_n$ are obtained by traversing the minima of $f_n(x)$ at each $n$, so my gut says that in the limit, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} g_n$ must also be equal to the minimum of the limit function $\min_{x \in X} f(x)$. It's like climbing a monotonous hill through a valley.

*Fact*: $\min_{x \in X} f(x) \geq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g_n$ can be proved.

If $f_n(x)$ were uniformly convergent to $f(x)$, the desired result would have been quite trivial, but unfortunately, I have no way to prove that either.

Could you please help me out. Any advice/solution would be greatly appreciated. I have tried to be as factually correct as possible, let me know in case of any errors.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay, I may have proven that $\{f_n\}$ do *not* converge uniformly to $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ and expand any $x$ in the eigenvector basis of $A$ as $x = \hat{x}_1 u_1 + \hat{x}_2 u_2$, so that $f_n(x)$ now reads as $\left[(\lambda_1^n\hat{x}_1^2+\lambda_2^n\hat{x}_2^2)/(\hat{x}_1^2+\hat{x}_2^2)\right]^{1/n},\;\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2\neq 0$. This can be posed as a 1-D problem: $h_n(x) = [\lambda_1^n (1-x) +\lambda_2^n x]^{1/n},\; x \in [0,1]$ with $h(x) = \begin{cases} \lambda_1,\;x=0\\ \lambda_2,\;x\in(0,1] \end{cases}$. $\{h_n\}$ do not converge uniformly to $h$.